# Catchable fatal error: Object of class "" could not be converted to string in "" on line ""

Tags: php, class

I have this code:

```
class Date_Time{
private static $month;
private static $year;
private static $day;

public function Date_Time($format){
    return self::getDate($format);
}

public static function getDate($date_format){
    return self::replace_date_string($date_format);
}

public static function replace_date_string($string){
    if(preg_match("/m/", $string)){
        $string = preg_replace("/m/", self::getMonth(), $string);
    }

    if(preg_match("/Y/", $string)){
        $string = preg_replace("/Y/", self::getYear(), $string);
    }

    return $string;
}

public static function getMonth(){
    return date("m");
}

public static function getYear(){
    return date("Y");
}
}
```

But if I print it like this:

```
$date = new Date_Time("Y");
echo $date;
```

It gives me an error that says:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Date_Time could not be converted to string in index.php on line 2

How can I fix this that it doesn't give me an error and what is making this error.

Comment: You need to provide a string representation of the object. Right now it has no idea how to write the date/time; it's just 3 numbers which it doesn't understand.

Comment: @Dave But If I use: `$date->getDate("Y")` it works.

Comment: yes, because that is an int, and PHP already knows how to translate ints into strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `__toString()` method

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->getYear() .'-'. $this->getMonth() .'-'. $this->getDay();
}
```

This method is need when you try to print whole object.

For PHP4 :

```
public function toString() {
    return $this->getYear() .'-'. $this->getMonth() .'-'. $this->getDay();
}
```

and call this method manually:

```
$date = new Date_Time("Y");
echo $date->toString();
```

Comment: Will that be supported in PHP 4?

Comment: No the class is supposed to be for users using PHP4 up to PHP5.5.

Comment: In PHP4, you can't use `private` `protected` `public`

Comment: @user3088257 Or use [try catch](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php) for catching an error when printing object and call in catch() block this `toString()` method automatically. I think it's a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to implement a magic method `__toString()` that returns the string representation.

Comment: Will that be supported in PHP 4?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor return object not value. So avoid the return from constructor:

```
$date = new Date_Time();
echo $date::getDate("Y");
```

With your current code, you could also manually call the constructor as below(But its not a good way):

```
$date = new Date_Time("Y");
echo $date->Date_TIme("Y");
```